# How can I restrict multiple groups or users to specific folders with SFTP?

Tags: sshd

I know how to restrict users of groups to their home folders and remove terminal access, but I cannot seem to get it working for multiple groups.

I have two groups:

```
groupA
groupB
```

## My `sshd_config`

```
Match Group groupa
   ChrootDirectory %h
   ForceCommand internal-sftp
   AllowTcpForwarding no
   PermitTunnel no
   X11Forwarding no
Match Group groupb
   ChrootDirectory %h
   ForceCommand internal-sftp
   AllowTcpForwarding no
   PermitTunnel no
   X11Forwarding no
```

When I try to access the server with a user in groupa over SFTP using Cyberduck, it works. However, it fails for users in groupb. For that matter, I can't even get `Match User userb` to work.

Permissions of /home/userb (whose primary group is groupb): `drwx------`

## OS Version: Arch Linux

```
4.4.3-1-ARCH #1 SMP PREEMPT Fri Feb 26 15:09:29 CET 2016 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

## OpenSSH Version

```
OpenSSH_7.2p1, OpenSSL 1.0.2g  1 Mar 2016
```

Comment: @Jakuje Is that even a question? "Can not create SFTP user Debian 7" Not very descriptive, nor findable. It does seem like your answer there solves my question, however. I would agree that there may be a duplicate answer case. I disagree that there is a duplicate question.

Comment: You didn't provide any error message or whatever to see what is going on there. But permissions are usually problem. Hope it helped. The answers are what matters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the benefit of future readers, the answer is twofold:

The permissions of the user's folders must be at least 755 (so that "other" can read and execute/enter the directory--and in reality, the group permissions should be irrelevant)

```
drwxr-xr-x
```

The ownership is irregular. The folders (in my case, the /home/usera and home/userb folders as variable in sshd_config: `%h`) must be owned by user `root` group `root`.
Ownership

```
 4 drwxr-xr-x  5 root                 root      4096 27. Okt 15:07 usera/
 4 drwxr-xr-x  2 root                 root      4096 13. Okt 13:35 userb/
```

This was wrecking havic with symbolic links inside of the chroot environment. So far, I could only get bindings to work by creating a subfolder of the user directory and making it owned by the corresponding user (not root). Then creating a binding (to another dir outside of the chrooted environment) within /etc/fstab.

e.g.

```
/media/5TB/My-Share    /home/usera/My-Share    none    defaults,bind 0 0
```

and /home/usera/My-Share

```
4 drwxr-s---  3 usera groupa 4096  5. Mär 15:59 My-Share/
```